# Quickbooks Invoice API not carrying over Item prices

Tags: json, api, quickbooks, invoice

I am POSTing the JSON below to this endpoint: https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/46208199999281740670/invoice

```
{
    "Line": [
        {
            "Description": "Conf #16209",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "Qty": 1,
                "UnitPrice": "2.01",
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "Conf #16209"
                }
            },
            "LineNum": 1,
            "Amount": "2.01",
            "Id": 1
        },
        {
            "Description": "Conf #16215",
            "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
            "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                "Qty": 1,
                "UnitPrice": "4.05",
                "ItemRef": {
                    "name": "Conf #16215"
                }
            },
            "LineNum": 2,
            "Amount": "4.05",
            "Id": 2
        }
    ],
    "CustomerRef": {
        "value": "1"
    }
}
```

The two items show up in Quickbooks correctly, but the item amounts (and therefore invoice total) are all blank, despite being present in the payload, as seen below:
[image: screenshot inside quickbooks]

I have scoured the docs, but must be missing something.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing to pass item reference value , which is mandatory. [image]

So your json should include item unique identifier in value field.please check above example json in documentation https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/invoice